# Custom script throwing `Permission denied` when I have all permissions and ownership of the files, could the reason be the file location?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, chown

I placed the main script in: `/usr/local/bin/`

Its files (data and scripts to source) in `/usr/local/custom-script/`

I used `chown` on all files and `custom-script` directory to give a normal user the ownership

Then I used `chmod 666` / `chmod 777` respectively to all files

---

I have all the permissions and ownership, but for a normal user the main file in `bin` throws:

`line 6: /usr/local/custom-script/utils.sh: Permission denied`

That line matches where I try to source `utils.sh` in the main script

---

Is it because I placed my `custom-script` directory in `/usr/local/`?

Then what's the right place to put that directory?

Comment: Scripts needs the execute bit set, which `chmod 666` won't accomplish. Try changing the perms to 755 across the board.

Comment: Wow that worked but I don't understand why, I'll google about it, thank you so much!